# Down menu and tablet

Tags: html, css, menu, touch, tablet

I have a small piece of code that displays a small pop-up menu in CSS but it does not work well with a tablet because the "hover" can not be implemented.

How do you simply enhance the menu you can scroll with one touch of a touch screen?

```
 <html>
 <head>
<title>Test</title>
<style type="text/CSS">
#menu ul {
margin:0;
padding:0;
list-style-type:none;
text-align:center;
}
#menu li {
float:left;
margin:auto;
padding:5px;
background-color: #2672ec;
font-family: "Segoe UI Light","Segoe UI Web Light","Segoe UI Web Regular","Segoe UI","Segoe UI Symbol","HelveticaNeue-Light","Helvetica Neue",Arial,sans-serif;
font-weight: bold;
color:white;
}
#menu li a {
display:block;
color:white;
text-decoration:none;
padding:5px;
border: 1px solid #2672ec;
}
#menu li a:hover {
border: 1px solid #ffffff;
}
#menu ul li ul {
display:none;
}
#menu ul li:hover ul {
display:block;
}

#menu li:hover ul li {
float:none;
}

</style>
<!--[if !IE]> <-->
<style type="text/CSS">
#menu li ul {
position:absolute;
}
</style>
<!--> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>
<style type="text/CSS">
#menu li ul {
position:absolute;
}
</style>
<![endif]-->

 </head>

 <body>

 <div id='menu'>
<ul>
    <li>Select menu &#9660;

    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Modify</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Delete</a></li>
    </ul>

    </li>
</ul>
 </div>

 </body>

 </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

What ever you want to change to work with touch screens add `:focus`

**take this**
`.example:hover{......}`

**Change to this**
`.example:hover, .example:focus{......}`